# Why do I scrape corrupted PDFs of same size with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I went through similar topics here but did not find anything helpful for my case.

I managed to get all PDFs (for personal learning purposes) in local folder but cannot open them. They also have the same (310 kB) size. Perhaps, you find some mistake in my code. Thanks.

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# define the URL to scrape
url = 'https://www.someweb.de/medikamente/arzneimittellisten/medikamente_i.html'

# define the folder to save the PDFs to
save_path = r'C:\PDFs'

# create the folder if it doesn't exist
if not os.path.exists(save_path):
    os.makedirs(save_path)

# make a request to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# parse the HTML content of the page
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# find all links on the page that contain 'href="/medikamente/beipackzettel/"'
links = soup.find_all('a', href=lambda href: href and '/medikamente/beipackzettel/' in href)

# loop through each link and download the PDF
for link in links:
    href = link['href']
    file_name = href.split('?')[0].split('/')[-1] + '.pdf'
    pdf_url = 'https://www.someweb.de' + href + '&file=pdf'
    response = requests.get(pdf_url)
    with open(os.path.join(save_path, file_name), 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
        f.close()
    print(f'Downloaded {file_name} to {save_path}')
```

Comment: Try to open the corrupted PDF file with a hex viewer or a text editor. Maybe it is an HTML page with an error message.

Comment: I think you are right. How can I fix it?

Comment: The error message may give hints.

Comment: URLs of the form *https://www.apotheken-umschau.de/medikamente/beipackzettel/insuman-basal-100-ieml-injekt-suspiepatrone-8922845.html&file=pdf* **do not** provide a path to a PDF

Comment: you can get to PDFs through https://www.apotheken-umschau.de/medikamente/arzneimittellisten/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues here:

- Select your elements from the list more specific, used [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

  ```
  soup.select('article li a[href*="/medikamente/beipackzettel/"]')
  ```
- Check the responses you get from your requests if expected elements are available and what the behavior looks like.

  - You will notice that you will have to iterate more levels as you have done.

    ```
    for link in soup.select('article li a[href*="/medikamente/beipackzettel/"]'):
        soup_detail_page = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.apotheken-umschau.de' + link.get('href')).content)

        for file in soup_detail_page.select('a:-soup-contains("Original Beipackzettel")'):
            soup_file_page = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.apotheken-umschau.de' + file.get('href')).content)
    ```
  - You will notice that the PDF is displayed in an IFRAME and you have to scrape it via external url

    ```
    pdf_url = soup_file_page.iframe.get('src').split('?file=')[-1]
    ```
  - You will notice that there are not only Beipackzettel for download

##### Example

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# define the URL to scrape
url = 'https://www.apotheken-umschau.de/medikamente/arzneimittellisten/medikamente_i.html'

# define the folder to save the PDFs to
save_path = r'C:\PDFs'

# create the folder if it doesn't exist
if not os.path.exists(save_path):
    os.makedirs(save_path)

# parse the HTML content of the page
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

# loop through each link and download the PDF
for link in soup.select('article li a[href*="/medikamente/beipackzettel/"]'):
    soup_detail_page = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.apotheken-umschau.de' + link.get('href')).content, 'html.parser')

    for file in soup_detail_page.select('a:-soup-contains("Original Beipackzettel")'):
        soup_file_page = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.apotheken-umschau.de' + file.get('href')).content, 'html.parser')
        pdf_url = soup_file_page.iframe.get('src').split('?file=')[-1]
        file_name = file.get('href').split('.html')[0].split('/')[-1] + '.pdf'

        with open(os.path.join(save_path, file_name), 'wb') as f:
            f.write(requests.get(pdf_url).content)
            f.close()
        print(f'Downloaded {file_name} to {save_path}')
```

Comment: thanks a lot! It got me closer. In the terminal it looks like the files are being downloaded, however, the save folder remains empty.

Comment: Did you use the example 1:1? Unfortunately, I cannot reconstruct the behaviour. Print the `pdf_url` and then call it up manually, to check that part. There may be deviations due to the access location or language.

Comment: I had an error in the save_path (working at 2 AM, my bad). So it is working with passing the additional argument 'features="lxml"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor. Thanks!

Comment: It is running for me, because I have `lxml` as standard installed, changed the example and set the `, 'html.parser'` as parameter. So you should get rid of the warnings.